# Editable DataGrid in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Is there any AngularJS module as for DataGrid which provides In-Line Editing? There is one in KendoUI
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

Can AngularJS & KendoUI be used together?

Comment: Have a look at this answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11892676/1057639

Comment: Thx Ganaraj. As per your exp with AngularJS, how difficult it is to write an Editable Data-Grid widget (as good as Kendo UI inline-editing datagrid), We are thinking abt porting a silverlight app to  AngularJS, How mature do you think AngularJS is right now.

Comment: I think angular is quite mature. Creating an editable data-grid widget with Angular should be a task that anyone who has some knowledge ( maybe a bit advanced! ) of Angular can achieve.

Comment: Hi Ganaraj Do you know anyone using AngularJS with SlickGrid? Any pointers would help, I am lookng for directive which wrap slickgrid

Comment: Have you tried writing a directive yourself? It is not really hard. If you go through my kendo-ui grid example and follow along and compare how that is done, it should be pretty straight forward. Also should be able to help you get started writing a directive for SlickGrid.

Comment: Why you would user kendo and angular together? I didn't know kendo, it seems cool.

Comment: ops but.....kendo is not free?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

check out [ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid)

templating, virtualization, simple data binding for selections, grouping, etc...

Comment: stay away from ng-grid. In its current state is too buggy and slow and has tons of problems, and version 3 is not ready to use.

Comment: @Agzam What are the alternatives? Commercial: KendoUI?

Comment: @Jury, honestly I have no definitive answer to this question. All different grid widgets I've tried never fully satisfied me. My biggest necessity is smooth scrolling with huge number of rows in the grid. I even posted this long question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676574/best-open-source-grid-with-smooth-infinite-scrolling and still awaiting for someone to answer it. For my own needs currently I chose ux-angularjs-datagrid. Although it's not full-fledged grid widget, many things you'd have to implement - like resizable, draggable columns, etc. But it's extremely fast

Comment: An alternative could be to use the trNgGrid: http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/index.html

Answer (score 10):

look at this quite generic example, where i loop first through rows and then through columns.
then a simple change between a span and an input field.
http://jsfiddle.net/3BVMm/3/

this would enable you to make inline editing with a few lines of code.

BUT: it doesnt work as expected, as there seems to be an bug, which I posted already on angular.

Comment: The bug is still there. If you type into any field it immediately exits.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use Smart Table.

Example, double click on an item in balance column: http://plnkr.co/edit/QQQd2znPqh87X2oQONd9?p=preview

```
  label: 'Balance',
  map: 'balance',
  isEditable: true,
  type: 'number',
```

<s>There is an **In-Line editing example** on the [home page](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#/section-edit) under **Edit cell** section. Cell edit mode is entered with double click.</s>

Github: [lorenzofox3 / Smart-Table](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table)

It has features like pagination, sorting, filtering, data formatting, row selection and it also generates a simple table structure which makes it easier to style/customize.

Comment: For future visitors, I believe the developer has removed editing from Smart-Table, as the section no longer exists.

Comment: Yes indeed, because is not relevant anymore. Now smart-table follows a declarative approach and you can extend it as you wish using the main controller API for table specific operations. Inline editing is not table specific but you will be able to use whatever edit directive you want inside the table with no extra work!

Comment: any example how will be great. like smart table most.

Comment: @MR.ABC: Added a link to a plunker example of how it is used.

Comment: Next will be the question when to save these... (Is it not declarative anymore?)

Comment: I haven't got to use it. I'd recommend to have a look at the source code(perhaps the tests https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/tree/master/test/spec) and the issues and if you can't find what you need to open a new issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try angular-xeditable.
For tables it has following:

- [editable row](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row)
- [editable column](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-column)
- [editable whole grid](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table)

Answer (score 4):

Kendo is working on AngularJS
http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/

Comment: hmm, price starting at $999 per developer

Comment: @JohnHenckel you're right, the time I wrote this answer it was free!

Answer (score 4):

The grid [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com) is able to do inline editing. It is an AngularJS directive, so plugs into your Angular app. Also comes with other standard grid features (selection, filtering etc).

The documentation page for editing is [here](http://angulargrid.com/angular-grid-editing/index.php)

To do editing, set editable to true in the column definition ie:

```
colDef.editable = true;
```

By default, the grid manages as a string value. If you want to do custom handling of the cell, eg to convert it into an integer, or to do validation, you provide a newValueHandler onto the column definition ie:

```
colDef.newValueHAndler = function(params) {
    var valueAsNumber = parseInt(params.newValue);
    if (isNaN(valueAsNumber)) {
        window.alert("Invalid value " + params.newValue + ", must be a number");
    } else {
        params.data.number = valueAsNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should expand and improve your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ng-table](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/16) directive allow to liven up your tables. It supports sorting, filtering and pagination. Header rows with titles and filters are automatically generated during compilation.

```
For example
```

[editable demo](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/16)

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own using richness of Angular. Perhaps you don't need to look for third party plugins.

I have made a basic sample that supports:-

1. Inline **Editing** of Binded-Data.
2. **Add new Row** on hitting last Grid-cell.

https://plnkr.co/edit/J0PeIlLsaASer4k8owdj?p=preview

Apply a simple css

```
.TextBoxAsLabel
{
   border: none;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: transparent;
    width:100%;
}

//for Dropdown    
.selectable::-ms-expand {   
  display: none; 
}
.selectable{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

hope it works, lemme know if any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The more recent open source angular grids I can see is ux-angularjs-datagrid, I haven't tried it but demos look promising...

https://github.com/webux/ux-angularjs-datagrid